# MySQL ordering with two dates

Tags: mysql, date

I m looking for the way to order my mysql data query according the fact i use 2 dates (created and modified). Evidently, modified is set when there is a come back on created.

I would like to order first priority to modified if exists or created.

Clearly i would like to show persons that visited the last in date independantly of came or came back.

QUERY :

```
SELECT userfrom, idrelation_user_visite_user FROM relation_user_visite_user WHERE userto = 1 AND SUBSTR(created,1,10) < '2013-12-13' ORDER BY created, modified DESC LIMIT 50
```

(!!!) IMPORTANT : Just understood that i have to make a kind of array (theorical) grouping created and modified, THEN, order all DESC

SRC -
SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relation_user_visite_user` (
  `idrelation_user_visite_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userfrom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idrelation_user_visite_user`),
  KEY `fk_relation_user_visite_user_users1` (`userfrom`),
  KEY `fk_relation_user_visite_user_users2` (`userto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1260 ;



INSERT INTO `relation_user_visite_user` (`idrelation_user_visite_user`, `created`, `modified`, `deleted`, `userfrom`, `userto`, `active`) VALUES
(61, '2013-12-13 15:26:08', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(64, '2013-10-21 22:48:04', '2013-11-24 21:10:24', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(93, '2013-10-23 13:24:30', '2013-11-09 16:06:47', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(132, '2013-10-24 20:07:39', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(202, '2013-10-27 21:40:29', '2013-11-15 00:58:37', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(311, '2013-11-03 18:28:49', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(379, '2013-11-06 13:40:50', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(407, '2013-11-06 18:27:50', '2013-11-06 18:48:18', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(521, '2013-11-09 16:06:36', '2013-12-10 19:16:21', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(563, '2013-11-11 22:51:46', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(722, '2013-11-18 05:08:09', '2013-11-18 05:21:37', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(765, '2013-11-18 20:11:17', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(859, '2013-11-23 01:04:11', '2013-12-10 18:48:50', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(935, '2013-11-27 16:15:36', '2013-12-02 11:48:24', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(982, '2013-12-01 18:00:48', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(992, '2013-12-02 14:21:46', '2013-12-05 12:25:08', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1011, '2013-12-03 09:19:59', '2013-12-03 20:22:11', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1019, '2013-12-03 11:09:08', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1026, '2013-12-03 15:47:07', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1053, '2013-12-03 22:36:42', '2013-12-03 22:45:56', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1055, '2013-12-03 23:27:10', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1066, '2013-12-04 10:53:18', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1081, '2013-12-04 12:57:26', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1122, '2013-12-04 23:39:14', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1154, '2013-12-05 22:21:23', '2013-12-10 00:01:58', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1185, '2013-12-06 22:12:15', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1246, '2013-12-09 19:10:12', '2013-12-09 19:57:12', NULL, 292, 1, 1),
(1259, '2013-12-10 18:55:07', NULL, NULL, 292, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Date format "datetime"

Comment: Seems that the way to do it would be :

gettin all created + modified in a sort of array, then sort by ordering all DESC

Comment: It appears that most of the answers have made the same wrong assumption about your problem statement - you were having a NULL value problem. Can you give sample data and what you would expect the ordered result set to look like?

Comment: Just done it :) sry for the time

Comment: What should the ordered result look like? i.e., the order of `idrelation_user_visite_user` ?

Comment: I made a new ticket that is more clear :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569425/mysql-order-with-two-dates-created-and-modified

Answer (score 4):

I assume you can't use simple `ORDER BY modified` because sometimes modifed is NULL. If so, use

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(modified, created)
```

The COALESCE function returns the first non-null value.

Comment: Doesn t work... seems that it returns first not null ordered than created ordered

Answer (score 2):

I assume when record is created them modified column is set to null so you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT userfrom, idrelation_user_visite_user
FROM relation_user_visite_user,
(CASE WHEN modified IS NOT NULL THEN modified 
ELSE created END) custom_order
WHERE userto = 1 
AND SUBSTR(created,1,10) < '2013-12-13' 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN modified IS NOT NULL THEN modified 
ELSE created END)
LIMIT 50
```

OR you can compare the columns

```
SELECT userfrom, idrelation_user_visite_user
FROM relation_user_visite_user 
WHERE userto = 1 
AND SUBSTR(created,1,10) < '2013-12-13' 
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN modified > created  THEN modified 
ELSE created END) DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Logicaly doesn t work coz workin on modified first, THEN, created... i need a mix of all the dates (created AND modified) THEN ORDER

Comment: that's what the case does, it works perfectly, it first creates an aggregated column, then sorts by it.

Answer (score 2):

use a case:

```
    SELECT userfrom, idrelation_user_visite_user ,
 case when modified is not null then modified else created end as last_visit
    FROM relation_user_visite_user 
    WHERE userto = 1 
    AND SUBSTR(created,1,10) < '2013-12-13' 
    ORDER BY 
    case 
    when modified is not null then modified 
    else created 
    end DESC 
limit 50
```

Comment: all was good order by but he needs also this case applied in select to see as virtual column and calling this by array,hats off to his question  +1 :)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT IF( modified IS NOT NULL, modified, created ) as orderdatas,
created, modified, userfrom, idrelation_user_visite_user 
FROM relation_user_visite_user 
WHERE userto = 1
AND SUBSTR(created,1,10) < '2013-12-13'
ORDER BY orderdatas DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: this what my first solution says `(CASE WHEN modified IS NOT NULL THEN modified 
ELSE created END)` difference is you have used if and i have used case,Both will give the same answer

Comment: the case is not making an array ? i use the select if to get the hole list of (created AND modified) the order on the hole

Comment: You mean you need an extra column `orderdatas` this is your array ?

Comment: a virtual one but not a real new column.
I would simply order all rows by those cases :
- if modified is not null forget created take modified
- collapse modified not null + created (created = case modified is null)
- order all
But the word 'simply' is makin me laugh :)

Comment: pseudo code? you cannot order by aliases reliably. M Khalid's answer and mine do the same as yours, except ours work, and they are valid in any sql, not jsutmysql

Comment: @AdrianBR - What do you mean _you cannot order by aliases reliably_? Are you saying MySQL doesn't reliably allow column aliases in its ORDER BY clause?

Comment: For sure this is doing same job, but not the job working for me :)  (modestly i mean) that shows rows treat by a case and another then... it treats modified,THEN, created. And i need a kind of alias that group modified and created and order both

Comment: @AgRizzo I use a lot of random versions of mysql for stat calculations, sometimes aliases are not recognised in the order by clause. Not sure if by design, or bug, or old version. I either use the column number(order by 3 desc) or the actual calculated value to avoid this issue. That makes it ugly to read, and harder to maintain, but at least it won't fail. This will also be compatible with other sql types.

Comment: @Titus, an entry cannot be modified before it is created, so modified will always be greater, unless there's a major flaw in the logic.

Comment: @AdrianBR - Your MySQL version had a bug then. Alias's are explicitly allowed to be used in the ORDER BY. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html: `The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses`

Comment: I dumbly thought that using id of the row will be good to order the hole datas... but as i guy can visit a person, if he revisit him after i up the column modified. Here are all my troubles... i should make a new ticket more clear

Comment: @AgRizzo you are right! :) I have had this issue though across more than one mysql server. Not sure on the version. Since then I stopped using that feature altogether